# Find the largest item in an array of objects and return name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create a function to find the largest item in an array of objects based on the price property of the objects. The function should accept the array of items as a parameter and return the name of the most expensive item.

My thought process here is to use .map() in order to loop over the array and target the price property. Then use .reduce() and Math.max() to find the largest number. This, i believe, i have done successfully thus far. Now i need to write the code to return the itemName that is associated with the previously returned largest price.

All of the above should be contained within the same function. Example of my code thus far below.

```
      let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Good Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Macbook Pro",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Center of Gravity",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

function mostExpensiveItem(items){
  let most = items.map(o => o.price).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
    })
    console.log(most)``
}
```

Comment: what if two or more items as result?

Comment: You should just use reduce and not use map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mostExpensiveItem(items) {
    return items.reduce((p, v) => p.price > v.price ? p : v).itemName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Good Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Macbook Pro",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Center of Gravity",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

var res = items.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  if(!acc.price || acc && acc.price < elem.price){
    acc = elem
  }
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(res.itemName)
```

Or, you can just sort descending on the basis of price and get the first element.

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Good Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Macbook Pro",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Center of Gravity",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

console.log(items.sort((a,b)=>  b.price - a.price)[0].itemName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of object with the same max proce and the map the name of the objects.

```js
let items = [{ itemName: "Good Habits", type: "book", price: 13.99 }, { itemName: "Macbook Pro", type: "computer", price: 299.99 }, { itemName: "Center of Gravity", type: "book", price: 15.00 }],
    result = items
        .reduce((r, o, i) => {
            if (!i || r[0].price < o.price) return [o];
            else if (r[0].price === o.price) r.push(o);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(({ itemName }) => itemName);

console.log(result);
```